# FadeIn and FadeOut not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have code to animate a navbar here is the javascript. The code works in chrome but not internet explorer.

```
var ref = document.referrer;
var loaded = 0;
var check = ref.search("<?php echo base_url(); ?>");
if ( check == -1 ) {
    loaded = 1;
}

$(".menu").mouseover( function() {
   if ( loaded == 1 ) {
      $(this).find("span.menu-hover").stop().fadeTo(800,.9,function(){});
   } else if ( loaded == 0 ) {
      //$(this).find("span.menu-hover").css("opacity",.9);
      loaded = 1;
   }
}).mouseout( function() {
   $(this).find("span.menu-hover").stop().fadeTo( 400, 0, function(){} );
});
```

Comment: Internet Explorer which version? If you are using jQuery 2.x you might get problems with older Internet Explorer Versions (< 9 at least)

Comment: Jquery 1.2.3 I was working a few different versions of Jquery due to plugins. The site works on my local machine but not on the live site.

Comment: Please update to a jQuery version that is not from 2008. The latest 1.x version works fine with every IE version. Also check the console in your IE for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks fine.
The new version of jQuery 2.x is not supported in IE versions 8 and down.
http://jquery.com/download/